# Why @PostMapping doesn't change th:if

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class AuthController {

private final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

private UserService userService;

public AuthController(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@GetMapping("login")
public String login(){
    return "auth/login";
}
@GetMapping("/profile")
public String profile(){
    return "auth/profile";
}
@GetMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    model.addAttribute("success",false);
    return "auth/register";
}
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        //show validation errors
        logger.warn("Validation errors were found while registering a new user");
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        model.addAttribute("validationErrrs",bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        return "auth/register";
    }else{
        User newUser = userService.register(user);
        redirectAttributes
                .addAttribute("id",newUser.getId())
                .addFlashAttribute("success",true);
        logger.info("No validation errors were found while registerning a new user");
        return "redirect:/register";
    }
}
@GetMapping("/activate/{email}/{activationCode}")
public String activate(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String activationCode) {
    Optional<User> user = userService.findByEmailAndActivationCode(email,activationCode);
    if( user.isPresent() ) {
        User newUser = user.get();
        newUser.setEnabled(true);
        newUser.setConfirmPassword(newUser.getPassword());
        userService.save(newUser);
        userService.sendWelcomeEmail(newUser);
        return "auth/activated";
    }
    return "redirect:/";
 }
 }
```

I call method registerNewUser and all time my logger display info about "No validation errors were found while registerning a new user" because else body is executed. So in my opinion redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success",true); should work correctly.
Unfortunately when I return "redirect:/register" I get new view but without allert depend on "succes" atribute. 
This is part of my view code:

```
<div class="row" th:if="${success}">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 alert alert-success" role="alert" >
    You have successfully registered with us. Please check your email to 
activate your account.
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>

<!-- User Registration form -->
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" 
th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}" th:if="!${success}">
<div class="row">
```

Somebody can help me pinpoint the cause of the lack of an alert?

Comment: This should work, can you show us the controller mapping of the `GET /register` mapping (= the one that actually returns the view)?

Comment: Updated description

Comment: Try adding it to the model, the same way you do it in the error part of your if. 
model.addAttribute("succes", true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `registerNewUser()` you're redirecting to `GET /register`. This will call the following method:

```java
@GetMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    model.addAttribute("success",false);
    return "auth/register";
}
```

In this method you're adding a model attribute `success` and you're setting it to `false`, effectively overriding the redirect attribute.

Since `RedirectAttributes` are used to populate the `Model` of the redirect target, you could wrap the `model.addAttribute(..)` call in an `if` statement. For example:

```java
@GetMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    if (!model.containsAttribute("success")) {
        model.addAttribute("success",false);
    }
    return "auth/register";
}
```

Alternatively, you could leave the model attribute away, as the parser is smart enough to evaluate `${success}` to `false` when it's missing. For example:

```java
@GetMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user",new User());
    return "auth/register";
}
```